# 500 internal server error in TinyMCE

Tags: magento

I m getting 500 internal server error when inserting image or anything that is open in separate pop up window in WYSIWYG TinyMCE editor in Magento backend CMS Page.

Comment: Make sure there are cirrectly privilegies set on folders and subfolders in magento. Find an adequate error message in your apache/logs/error.log file

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should look into the .htaccess file and modify the entry like below.

```
 change

 Options +FollowSymLinks

 into

 #Options +FollowSymLinks
```

I mean comment it.